# UILabel with rounded corner (Xcode 4.5 and iOS 6)

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uilabel

I've just added a UILabel componet into a view and I'm trying to make it a rounded corner UILabel. I’ve been reading some questions and answers related to the same issue but all of them says that I have to change the source code. Is it really necessary in the new Xcode 4.5 and iOS6? Also I’m not sure if I’m able to see the code generated by the mainstoryboard.

Any help will be appreciated.

Many thanks,
Marcos

Comment: Please accept my or Ismael's answer if they helped you. I wanna gain my reputation and Ismael as well i'm sure

Answer (score 10, accepted):

to make UILabel with rounded corners do the following:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

then you should refer to your UILabel

```
yourLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
```

5 is just an example, of course

Comment: Many thanks. Just one last question: Is there any specific place to add this code? I’m not sure if I have access to the code generated by the Xcode Interface Builder.  Is there any special method on the Controller where this code should be added?

Comment: Well, you should have an outlet variable UILabel* connected with the one you've created in IB. And you set the corner radius for this variable wherever you want it to do. viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear should work fine

Answer (score 11):

You can do it all in Interface Builder.
In *XCode*, select your `.xib` file (or your *storyboard*) to open Interface Builder. Click on your `UILabel` and open the *Identity inspector* (if you do not know where it is, go to XCode's *Help menu* and type in "*Identity inspector*"). Click the plus button under the *User Defined Runtime Attributes* pane, and write `layer.cornerRadius` for the *Key Path*, chose `Number` for the *Type*, and `5` (or any other number) for the *Value*.
If you run now your project you should get a round-cornered `UILabel`.

Comment: this only works if "clip subviews" is checked (I'm on Xcode 6)

Answer (score 2):

Add the quartzcore framework to your project frameworks

```
import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"
```

use following code -

```
label.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0; // radius depend on how much rounded corner you want.
label.clipsToBounds = TRUE;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `#import "QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h"` and somewhere on your code do

```
label.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0; // or whatever radius you want
```

Comment: Many thanks. Just one last question: Is there any specific place to add this code? I’m not sure if I have access to the code generated by the Xcode Interface Builder. Is there any special method on the Controller where this code should be added?

Comment: That depends on where your cell is. You need to have a reference to it on your controller, and if it's created by the interface builder, then you should add this on your `viewDidLoad` method

Comment: Very nice! I was able to do that. I added the code into the viewDidLoad method and it's working smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in interface builder by adding layer.cornerRadius as one of the keys in 'User Defined Runtime Attributes' under the 'Identity Inspector'.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would share a slightly better way to do it for newer development environments (with Swift).  With the following code, you get a special field appear in Interface Builder that lets you set the corner radius.  A new subsection appears within the Attributes Inspector called "View", in there is an item called "Corner Radius"

```
#if !os(watchOS)
    // watchOS UI designer allows setting of a corner radius.  For
    // iOS and tvOS, an Interface Builder extension is needed.
    extension UIView {
        @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
            get {
                return layer.cornerRadius
            }
            set {
                layer.cornerRadius = newValue
                layer.masksToBounds = newValue > 0
            }
        }
    }
#endif
```

Answer (score -1):

**Yes, it only can be done through adding code, mentioned by other guys here. Unfortunately Interface Builder can't do it now.**